# Existe algum problema em instanciar um Fragment duas vezes?

Tags: android

Tenho um Fragment que é o primeiro a ser aberto, é uma lista de itens!

Depois dependendo do botão clicado nos Cards dentro desse fragment ele abre uma tela com um TabLayout com algumas abas e uma dessas abas é justamente esse primeiro fragment que esta sendo reaproveitado mas ele deve carrega uma outra lista de itens. São o mesmo TIPO de itens mas é uma outra lista!!!

Toda vez que tento fazer isso ele é instanciado pelo FragmentPagerAdapter com a mesma lista de quando o APP foi aberto mesmo chamando o metodo correto para buscar outra lista!!!

Answer (score 1):

Não há problema algum, contanto que a cada chamada ele possua uma nova instância, o que com certeza é o caso.
Possuo uma aplicação que possui uma único fragmento para diversos momentos e nunca tive problema algum. Inclusive é sempre a melhor coisa aproveitar os códigos o máximo possível para não inchar o app desnecessariamente.

Espero ter ajudado!